# Is there any way to import a Python module in a string?

Tags: python, python-3.x, module, python-import

Let's say, I have a string defined in code as such:

```
module_string = """
def add(x, y):
    return x + y

def multiply(x, y):
    return x * y
"""
```

Is there any way to effectively do the following:

```
from module_string import add, multiply
```

---

[According to the Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path), a script will only search for modules as `.py` files in the directory containing the input script (or the current directory when no file is specified)." and then look for a module in the `PYTHONPATH` or the installation-dependent default.

An obvious method then would be to write the string to a file with suffix `.py` and then importing it. While this works, it's does create an actual file and a `__pycache__` directory in the working directory, which can be undesirable.

While it's possible to use `exec()` to simply execute the string as code, this does not behave as expected if the module string has an `__all__` defined or if there's a `if __name__ == '__main__':` part of the module that isn't meant to be executed when importing as a module.

Is there any way to get a string to behave like an importable module in Python without necessarily generating a bunch of files and directories in the working directory? Or is it absolutely necessary that a module must exist as a file? Is there some way of faking this via a `StringIO` object or something similar?

---

**Context:** I want to be able to dynamically import a module from a file in a Github Gist and dynamically update the imported classes/functions when the gist undergoes a revision. I am doing this by using GitHub's REST API to read in the Gist as a string via the `requests` module, but I need to find some way to get this string to be imported as a module within the code itself.

If my question is more of [an XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) instead, I would love to hear other suggestions on how to achieve my intended goal.

---

PS: Let's assume I have thought through all the various cyber-security issues related to this problem (as I know some people on SO will have the urge to focus on that aspect).

Comment: I understand the question but wouldn't it still make more sense to grab that file in the Gist and store it locally before loading it as a module?

Comment: If there's no other way to import a module via string, then that's the method I have to live with. But I want to find a way to do this without saving any files to disk. There may me 100s of Gists that I wish to import (for the project I have in mind, it will be other people writing and editing these Gists).

Comment: Maybe someone will prove me wrong, but I don't think there really is a reliable way to do this that would be preferable to using temporary files. If I had to solve this problem, I'd look into creating the temporary files in such a way that they appear in the correct location and get cleaned up automatically (using the `tempfile` library).

Comment: @Grismar Using the `temp` directory is an interesting suggestion, but how would one get Python's module importer to look at the temp directory? I guess, you could use `sys` to alter the `PYTHONPATH` to include the temp directory but that feels like an ugly solution (and probably not much better than just creating files in the current directory)!

Comment: I would suggest something like writing a class specifically for the purpose you described, which could set up a single root folder in the temp directory (and take care of cleanup, where needed) and anything pulled down to import would go in there, so there's only that one thing to add to the python path, which will be cleaned up when the folder is cleaned up.

Comment: @Grismar as a context manager!

Answer (score -2):

Probably not a great idea to execute code that you download, but if you really want to do it

```
>>> module_string = """
... def add(x, y):
...     return x + y
... 
... def multiply(x, y):
...     return x * y
... """
>>> exec(module_string)
>>> add(1,2)
3
```

Comment: OP already wrote "While it's possible to use exec() to simply execute the string as code, this does not behave as expected if [... etc.]" - this doesn't answer the question.